# fine-tuning bert for abstractive text summarization

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, summarization, fine-tuning

I am using BERT (araBert to be more specific) for Arabic abstractive text summarization, but I don't want to train all the parameters from scratch. What I am looking for is a way to freeze the layers and then add some layers (LSTM or Transformer layers) to train the model on my data.
How can I accomplish that?
Because training the model from scratch takes a lot of resources and time.
Thanks for your answers in advance

Tried the HuggingFace approach for fine-tuning summarization task, but it trains all the parameters.